# EE External Site API

Tags: open-api

First I am not a programmer so much may go over my head that you say.

I have been working on trying to come up with a solution to this...

Have an external site's form(Site B) post to my site(Site A) to a specific Channel.

I want to use an API of some sort that can post via REST/Javascript or CURL and do a postback if the insert was successful.  Does anyone know of an add-on that can do all this?  I know this exists in Wordpress but I am trying my best to hold onto EE, this is for a personal site of mine.  Really could use someones help, please and I will return the favor.

Answer (score 1):

The Import module from Solspace works well for getting data INTO your site from another service or API. If you want to provide an API interface for OTHER sites to post data into your site then you might look at "Entry API" (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-api). I've not tried the "Entry API" myself but came across it so I can't provide any info on how well it works.

Comment: Thanks Bob for that.  I have looked at Entry API and asked the developer regarding functionality but he said a post back was not possible.  You would think an API interface that cost $69 would do everything.

Comment: Posting data into an outside service/API from Exp Eng is almost always a custom code setup because there is such a wide difference from one API to another in things like what data to post and in what way to post it. I can understand how it would be difficult to provide a generic method of posting to any API when it is not built for a specific service.

Comment: I had hopes that it could be straight forward, all I need is the ability for posting and post back.

Comment: I'm afraid you're simplifying what goes on in 'post back'.I'd be interested in what Wordpress functionality you are talking about in your original post.

Comment: Bob that may be very true, the fact is I am looking for a true or false return if my system accepts the input from site B to my site (Site A).  I would also like to have the ability to give other data points back to the person sending the form request from their site.  Again this is something that goes beyond the norm for EE.  I have made this work mainly with using the add-on Open API for EE.

Comment: I've also come across the 'Export It' module that may work for what you want to do.